# Adjust code to remain on page when add to cart is triggered

Tags: html, wordpress, woocommerce

So I am using the following code to add a product to cart on woocommerce with a qty

<a href=”https://yourdomain.com/?add-to-cart=25&quantity=3">Add to Cart

It works and adds the products etc, but I need it to remain on the page the customer is on, currently this will of course takes us to the home page, i've tried this instead

<a href=”/?add-to-cart=25&quantity=3">Add to Cart

But this also takes me to home page once added, I just want to trigger the add to cart and stay

Comment: Remove the \ like this `<a href=”?add-to-cart=25&quantity=3">`

Comment: Why is it so simple!!!! Thank you thats exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

By default WooCommerce doesn't redirect you the cart page unless you turned on this option>>

[image]

Please check this setting from :

**www.your-website/wp-admin/ >> WooCommerce >> Settings >> Products**

and you will see it there.
If that solves your problem I'm glad to be help!

Comment: Nope thats not what I asked, I need the function of adding to cart, and then the user remains on the page they are on